# I can't figure out how to get a number from the DOM (JavaScritp)

Tags: javascript

So I am creating a small interactive story game to help me learn and practice JavaScript.

Anyway, I am able to create a number and put it into the DOM (exactly where I want), but am having trouble taking that number back out of the DOM to use in a function.

I have been at this for the last four hours, and after scouring through the internet I have turned, once again, to the number one place to receive answers.

So, just to clarify it with a little more detail; I have created a variable that creates an "attack" number and places it in the DOM. But when I try to use it in a function to minus from a foes life, I have no success.

Here is the code:

```
var bandit1Life = 20;
var bandit1Attack = 3;
//Declares the life and attack of the enemy.

var yourAttack = Number(document.getElementById("attackvalue").value);
//This runs as null. Along with the many other variations I have tried. I also get NaN with another variation I thought was closer (I will include that below).

var fightAttack = {
    pressAttack: function() {
    var e = bandit1Life - yourAttack.value;
    console.log(e);
    }
};
//This is the function that runs when the corresponding button is pressed - I console.log it to test if it works before placing it into the DOM.
```

And here is the variation I thought was closer but returns NaN, even when I add .value on the end:

```
var yourAttack = yourAttackNum;
```

Here is where the value is created (within the p element).

```
<p id="attackValue"> </p>
```

Comment: How does the corresponding HTML look like?

Comment: you're also using yourAttack.value when you've already got the value from the element. and like others have said you should use innerHTML or innerText

Comment: I have tried .innerHTML, but will will try .innerText now.

Comment: .innerText does also not work.

Comment: It does not work because the id on your paragraph is `attackValue` and in your code you try selecting `attackvalue` - id's are case sensitive.

Comment: what is  yourAttackNum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your element is not an input or other interactive element, you should use innerHTML or innerText to gets its content. Also bear in mind that the ID is case-sensitive (so you must specify `attackValue`, not `attackvalue`).

Demo:

```js
var bandit1Life = 20;
var bandit1Attack = 3;
var yourAttack = Number(document.getElementById("attackValue").innerText);
console.log(yourAttack);

var fightAttack = {
  pressAttack: function() {
    var e = bandit1Life - yourAttack;
    console.log(e);
  }
};


fightAttack.pressAttack()
```

```html
<div id="attackValue">32</div>
```

Comment: I am still getting NaN from this.

Comment: @DylanT25 Did you actually run my demo above? Press "Run code snippet" to see it working. If you're still having a problem, double-check to make sure your code is matching mine exactly. Of course, in your original example, your `<p>` doesn't actually contain any content, so there's nothing to convert into a number. Whereas mine contains a value (32). Maybe that's the issue? Or maybe you are running the code before the element exists in your page. Ensure you place it inside an "onload" block, or alternatively simply place your JavaScript as the last thing before your `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: I ran the code on here and it worked, on my editor it did not. then I noticed I had previously attacked .value on the yourAttack in the function - after removing this it worked. Thank you so much, this has been driving me crazy for a good few hours now. I am still a beginner in JavaScript and after a few courses on the fundamentals I decided the best way to learn was by trying to create something. So here I am... lol. Again thank you so much :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the same name for your id and getElementById, as they're case sensitive e.g. attackValue, not attackvalue.

also because it's not an input it won't have the value prop use innerText

you also need a value within the p tag otherwise will create NaN

```
Number(undefined) // NaN
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText

```js
const bandit1Life = 20;
const bandit1Attack = 3;

const yourAttack = Number(document.getElementById("attackValue").innerText);

const fightAttack = {
  pressAttack: () => {
    const e = bandit1Life - yourAttack;
    console.log(e);
  }
};


fightAttack.pressAttack()
```

```html
<p id="attackValue">2</p>
```

Comment: By "the same name" Joe means that id's are case sensitive.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing them case sensitive, but have been re-writing it so much I must have missed that this time lol. But anyway, neither innerText, nor innerHTML works.

Comment: well it does it runs in my example, is there any errors in the console? what i imagine is happening is the dom hasnt loaded when your script is ran